# How to create profile image stack animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a profile image stack animation in Flutter as shown in the attached video (You can go to the attached video link).

The concept is when we add a new image in the image list, then it will be added to the profile stack with fade and slide in animation and previous images should slide to the next position in the image stack also the last image should be removed with fade and slide out animation.

Video URL : [Profile_Image_Stack_Animation.MP4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L6EZk29-Mxfipb7ZGB1oPWHwuNuxvx9l/view?usp=sharing)

I tried with simple animated widget and some animation controllers but, It didn't workout.

Let me know if anyone has the ideology of steps to create this kind of animation or if anyone has ever created this kind of animation using Flutter then any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can check below libraries

https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_stack
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_stack